Mathml is not showing as formula in microsoft word
I am creating a docx generator using docxtemplater. I am injecting Mathml data to show math equation when generating the docx. But it's showing raw mathml in the doc, not equation. I am using word 2016.
showing like this in doc
What is the reason? What can i do tio show the math formula in docx.
If you can, please help me. Thanks.
I am trying to show math formula in docx, but it's showing raw mathml.
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><semantics><mrow><msub><mo>∑</mo><mstyle scriptlevel="1"><mtable rowspacing="0.1em" columnalign="center" columnspacing="1em"><mtr><mtd><mstyle scriptlevel="1" displaystyle="false"><mrow><mn>0</mn><mo>≤</mo><mi>i</mi><mo>≤</mo><mi>m</mi></mrow></mstyle></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd><mstyle scriptlevel="1" displaystyle="false"><mrow><mn>0</mn><mo>&lt;</mo><mi>j</mi><mo>&lt;</mo><mi>n</mi></mrow></mstyle></mtd></mtr></mtable></mstyle></msub><mi>P</mi><mo stretchy="false">(</mo><mi>i</mi><mo separator="true">,</mo><mi>j</mi><mo stretchy="false">)</mo></mrow><annotation encoding="application/x-tex">\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le m\\ 0\lt j\lt n}} P(i,j)</annotation></semantics></math> 

Can you show what your code looks like right now. Also, Please take a moment to review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

you can use the mathjax or katex to render the equation view

Hello Ashik, I'm the creator and maintainer of docxtemplater. Did you try by using a tag starting with a @ sign ? That is a raw xml tag : https://docxtemplater.com/docs/tag-types/#raw-xml
I'm not sure if it works but it could
